# Prove this map is an automorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to understand the proof for this problem.

Let $G$ be a group, and let $g \in G$. Let $\phi_{g}(x)=gxg^{-1}$ for all $x$ in $G$. Show that $\phi_{g}$ is an automorphism of $G$.

Proof. Since $G$ is a group, we have $\phi_{g}(x)=gxg^{-1} \in G$ for all $x \in G$. (How does this fact follow from $G$ being a group??)

I can put the rest of the proof up if necessary, but for the moment I am stuck on this part.

Comment: $gxg^{-1}$ is the product of three elements of $G$, so it is in $G$. Could you be more precise on your doubt? Where could the elements $gxg^{-1}$ be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Since $G $ is a group , we have

$$(\forall (a,b)\in G^2) \;\; ab\in G $$
and $$a^{-1}\in G $$

thus

$$(\forall x\in G) \;\;\;gxg^{-1}=(gx)g^{-1} \in G .$$

Take $y\in G $ .

then

$$\phi_g (x)=y \iff g xg^{-1}=y $$
$$\iff x=g^{-1}yg $$

this proves that $\phi_g $ is bijective.

Answer (score 3):

Because a group is multiplicative closed

$$g_{1},g_{2}\in G\rightarrow g_{1}g_{2}\in G$$

In your case $g,x,g^{-1}\in G$, and so as $gxg^{-1}\in G$.

Answer (score 2):

This is directly from the definition of a group: if $a,b\in G$ then $ab\in G$, along with associativity: if $a,b,c\in G$ then $abc=a(bc)=(ab)c$. Also, $g^{-1}\in G$ if $g\in G$. So $gxg^{-1}=(gx)g^{-1}\in G$.